# Insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint inside sequelize transaction

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

There is `update` query inside transaction. I get **insert or update on table "comp_submissions" violates foreign key constraint "comp_submissions_comp_id_fkey"**
Looks like comp is not added into database table yet. However, what is curious is, `CompAddressRel` model is actually created with `comp.id` value

```
await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
  const comp = await Comp.create({
    ...req.body,
    submitted_by_id: req.user.id,
    is_files_uploaded: false,
    publishedAt: req.body.is_public ? new Date() : null,
    status: APPROVED
  }, { transaction: t })

  // This works
  await CompAddressRel.create({
    comp_id: comp.id,
    address_detail_pid: address.address_detail_pid,
    building_id: req.body.building_id,
    land_id: req.body.land_id,
    campaign_id: req.body.campaign_id,
    owner_id: req.body.owner_id,
    planning_permit_id: req.body.planning_permit_id
  }, { transaction: t })


  // This doesn't work
  await CompSubmission.update({
    status: APPROVED,
    comp_id: comp.id
  }, {
    where: {
      id: req.body.submission_id
    }
  }, { transaction: t })
})
```

Both `CompSubmission`, and `CompAddressRel` have comp_id as a foreign key.
Only `CompSubmission` doesn't work

Comment: Were you able to make this work? I am facing exact issue

Comment: The problem is sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't :D

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using promise, see my code below.

```
async createUser(user: UserDTO) {
 let usr;
 await db.sequelize.transaction().then(async t => {
      return await Organizations.createOrganization(
        {
          name: user.organizationName,
          type: user.organizationType
        },
        { ...t }
      )
        .then(async organization => {
         usr = await userRepo.create(
            {
              ...user,
              // @ts-ignore
              Organization: organization.id,
              // @ts-ignore
              organizationName: org.organizationName,
              // @ts-ignore
              organizationType: org.organizationType
            },
            { ...t }
          );
         return usr
        })
        .then(t.commit.bind(t))
        .catch(t.rollback.bind(t));
    });
   return usr
  }
```